# How to save the output of print statement in new csv file

Tags: python

I need to select the values of a specific parameter from csv file and copy the output to a new csv file.

I have an issue with saving the output to a new file.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import codecs
myifile=open('Log_01.csv',"rb")
read=csv.reader(codecs.iterdecode(myifile, 'UTF-8'))
myList=['11:PRTD 1']
for row in read:
    if row[0] in myList:
        print(row)
```

```
[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mre].

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
with open('Log_01.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    with open('eggs.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfileWrite:
        spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfileWrite, delimiter=' ',
                                quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

        for row in spamreader:
            spamwriter.writerow(row)
```